# Office 365 API Calendar: push data when new event PHP

Tags: php, api, calendar, ms-office, office365

Tools:

- Php (programming language)
- MySQL database (to store events)
- Office 365 API (to interact with calendars from office 365)

I'm making a small system that reads in the events from a calendar every 5 minutes and displays them on a webpage. I achieve this by auto-refreshing the page every 5 minutes `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">`, when the page gets loaded it calls the API to get the newest events.

I chose to pick an auto-refresh rate because I didn't find any possibility/setting to make the calendar push data to my webpage when a new event is created. This would be better because then the webpage doesn't have to refresh every 5 minutes.

So my question: can the calendar of office 365 push data/generate a signal to my webpage so it can refresh only when the calendar has new event? If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another choice is to use [Notifications REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations), the API could be used to subscribe to changes in your calendar, mailbox, and contacts .You could get notifications for  a top level entity collection of messages, events or contacts, below example shows how to subscribe to new events :

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
   @odata.type:"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
   Resource: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events",
    NotificationURL: "https://mywebhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",  
   ChangeType: "Created",
   ClientState: "c75831bd-fad3-4191-9a66-280a48528679"
}
```

When a triggering event occurs ,Office 365 pushes a notification via a webhook to the callback URL. Your app, in turn, takes actions according to your business logic, for example , update your local cache, corresponding client views, or backend system upon changes.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of this part of the API.